# Remove element from android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I am trying to create a list view that can support side swipe. I want the user to be able to drag a listview element to the right and off screen reveling a delete button below. The user should be able to click the delete button to remove that element from the listview. I have been following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCHNAi9kJI4 but just need help on adding the delete button to the background. Any help?

Comment: The delete button should just remove the item from the adaptor, and then call notifyDataSetChanged to reset the listview.

Comment: @GabeSechan- yes but how to i place that delete button?

Comment: @Samantha Design your layout with 2 layouts. 1 is delete button and other one is the actual field. By default set the delete button visibility to gone. And at the time of swiping show the delete button.

Answer (score 12):

in your Adapter fill() write this code

```
imgDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 

                 adapter.remove(item);

            }
        });
```